# Can gRPC bidi streaming server send a message to a client that it is not currently responding to?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Can gRPC bidi streaming server respond out of sequence to a client ? 
All examples on the net show server responding to an incoming request only. 
The **StreamObserver**  interface contains implementation for the response responding to a request
In **onNext** method, can the **StreamObserver parameter** be cached and reused later to send messages ?
What I need :
I have cached the StreamObserver on the first request for Client1
On a request from Client**2**, I need to send a message to Client1

Using the cached StreamObserver  object throws a CANCELLED error and I notice onComplete is called for the first request from Client1   
Is there a way to do this ? 
[This](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/779) seems to be a similar ask, but was not supported 2015, and am not sure if this now possible

Comment: already answered for the most part here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394150/grpc-how-can-i-distinguish-bi-streaming-clients-at-server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the server receives the `StreamObserver` for responses to the client it can call the object from any thread at any time (although the object is not thread-safe, so concurrent calls are not permitted). There's no need to couple it with incoming requests in `onNext()`.

The client calling `onComplete()` is normal and does not end the RPC. If your code turns around and calls `onComplete()`, however, at that point you can no longer send any more messages on the stream. You will probably want to observe client cancellations, which can be achieved by casting the `StreamObserver` to `ServerCallStreamObserver` and calling [`setOnCancelHandler(Runnable)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/ServerCallStreamObserver.html#setOnCancelHandler-java.lang.Runnable-) at the start of the RPC.